# C# Merge two json and remove missing property

Tags: c#, json, merge, json.net

i am working with **two unknown** json (i don't know structure) and i need to merge these two, i also have to remove missing properties, I know I probably haven't explained myself very well, so I'll give you an example.

Json 1:

```
{
  'FullName': 'Dan Deleted',
  'Deleted': true,
  'DeletedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00',
  'location': {
    'nation': 'it',
    'city': 'Madrid'
  }
}
```

Json 2:

```
{
  'FullName': 'Dan',
  'Age': '23',
  'DeletedDate': '2014-01-20T00:00:00',
  'location': {
    'nation': 'es'
  }
```

what I would:

```
{
  'FullName': 'Dan',
  'Deleted': true,
  'DeletedDate': '2014-01-20T00:00:00',
  'location': {
    'nation': 'es',
    'city': 'Madrid'
  }
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json and i've saw that there is a method merge  `json1.merge(json2)`  but in this way i will get something like that:

```
{
  "FullName": "Dan",
  "Deleted": true,
  "DeletedDate": "2014-01-20T00:00:00",
  "location": {
    "nation": "es",
    "city": "Madrid"
  },
  "Age": "23"
}
```

I hope you understand.
In practice I would like that if the property is present in **both json**, in the result the **value is that of json2**, but if a property is present **only in json2**, in the result this **should not be there**. While if it is **only in json1** then **it will be in the result**.

How could I do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: And how are you going to merge if you even don't know a structure? Can you show the code you have tried  already? And city for example only in one json, not in both

Comment: do you compare properties json1 and json2 ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Newtonsoft's example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) its a matter of which `JObject` it is invoked on and which other `JObject` is passed in as an argument. The one passed in by argument is the one that overwrites. Given these parameters, you will want to get the API responses as a string and then deserialize with `JObject.Parse(string)`

Also note that prior to the merge you can probably run some validation logic on these parsed objects to suit your needs

You should probably also explore the [`JsonMergeSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonMergeSettings.htm) object that is shown in the example, as it may include some finer grained options that you may want for your merge